# WinAPI What happens if I don't Translate and Dispatch unhandled message

Tags: c++, winapi

On [GetMessage reference from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) we have the next example:

```
BOOL bRet;

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

What if I just ignore unhandled messages in the main loop of my program and move on?

Is there any risk to it? Will Windows complain/leak memory/hold resources for longer than necessary if I don't translate+dispatch this message if I don't actually need/want to handle it?

Comment: The whole of the UI (and other functionality) is message based - if you don't process messages nothing will happen; no windows will be drawn, no buttons clicked etc

Comment: Why bother running a message loop at all if you don't want to handle messages?

Comment: You  might want to try it to see what happens. Then you can ask the deeper question of why not handling messages causes your program to break.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The code was provided by Microsoft as an example of error detection (the `bRet == -1` part), not an example of message handling. (The emphasis is on not treating the return value of `GetMessage` as a simple Boolean.)

Comment: I handle 2-3 buttons inside this loop now, I just wonder what would happen with others and will I interfere with other programs by "touching" this messages

Comment: _"...other programs..."_ no this is your message loop.

Comment: I'm curious about your reasons for not translate and dispatch unhandled messages. For win32 windows, `DefWindowProc` will provide default processing for any window messages that an application does not process.

Comment: *"What if I just ignore unhandled messages"* - I don't understand the question. Ignoring a message makes it handled. You cannot ignore a handled message. What is the real question here?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT `DefWindowProc` is called by `DispatchMessage` so without this nothing will happen.

Comment: @a_girl Related: [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493), though it talks about *filtering* messages, and you are asking about *dispatching* messages, which are two different things, but the end result is the same - windows don't receive the messages they need to do their jobs correctly.

Comment: @RichardCritten technically, `DispatchMessage()` calls a window's current message procedure, which then decides whether to call `DefWindowProc()` or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @IInspectable I interpret "unhandled messages" as "messages for which the program does not provide handlers" and "just ignore" as "do not call `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage`". So the real question is *what happens if `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` are commented out of the provided code example?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [The Message Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages#the-message-loop),

> The TranslateMessage function is related to keyboard input. It
> translates keystrokes (key down, key up) into characters. You do not
> really have to know how this function works; just remember to call it
> before DispatchMessage. The link to the MSDN documentation will give
> you more information, if you are curious.
>
> The DispatchMessage function tells the operating system to call the
> window procedure of the window that is the target of the message. In
> other words, the operating system looks up the window handle in its
> table of windows, finds the function pointer associated with the
> window, and invokes the function.

If I don't translate+dispatch, loop will not be able to handle keyboard input and window messages. For example, the window cannot be moved, cannot be redrawn or closed. This has nothing to do with memory leaks

Having said that, a standard Message loop should be:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Accelerators are what matters here, otherwise known as "short-cut keys". Your program wants to respond to them regardless of which window has the focus. Like F1 shows the program's help file, regardless which control has the focus. You don't want to have to write code that subclasses every control window to recognize F1.

Refer: [why exactly TranslateMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581889/why-exactly-translatemessage)

Comment: Thank you for providing useful explanation